# Drupal migration / local development

Tags: 6, migrations

I have a Drupal site which is online, and I'm going to do some maintenance on it. That means I need to have a local copy to do some testing first. They've given me a copy of the site on a folder "/mysite.co.uk" and this contents:

[image: files]

(.htaccess file was renamed)

I've installed Drupal on a VM, imported the DB, updated some fields which pointed to "modules/sites/mysite.co.uk/modules/..." and the site seems to work OK.

However, when I try to access some modules, like say, simplenews, it gives me a "Failed opening required 'sites/all/modules/simplenews/simplenews.admin.inc" or undefined functions...

Of course, I could go and download every module it complains about. But that's no good. My suspicion is that they had this site installed in a multi-site environment and now I'm missing all the global/common files. Could this be the issue? If so, how could I perform a migration, should I ask for the global installation files?

Comment: Well yes, if you want to use modules in a Drupal site the files need to exist. It's impossible for us to speculate how a particular shared hosting provider may have their server set up. You'd need to ask them

Comment: @Clive, thanks. I forgot to clarify that I don't have much experience with Drupal. So it may seem obvious but I wasn't sure if I was on the right track.

Comment: Yep, definitely on the right track - a typical multisite will have sites/[site-name]/modules for site-specific stuff, and sites/all/modules for 'global' stuff. Your suspicions are probably spot on, you need the sites/all folder to get it working